# Calling a ref from another component (?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with React in a chat application. I need that evertytime you click on the chat box the input where you enter your messagges, should be focused.

The problem I have is that the chat box which is in the main component, is separately from the component where the input to enter the messages is.

Look, **main component**

```
class ChatView extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this._inputFocus = this._inputFocus.bind(this);
  }

  _inputFocus () {
    let input = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.SHOULDFOCUS-HERE);
    input.focus();
  }
  render () {

    if (this.props.mode === 'player') {
      dealerPlayerMessages = <ul ref="messages">{messages}</ul>;

      // CHAT FORM IS THE COMPONENT CONTAINING THE INPUT
      chatForm = <ChatForm onAddMessage={this.addMessage} />;

      chatBox = <div>{dealerPlayerMessages}{chatForm}</div>
    }

    return <div className="dealer-player-box" onClick={this._inputFocus} >
      {chatBox}
    </div>;
  }
}
```

so, as you see, when you click in the div with class name `dealer-player-box`, the function `this._inputFocus` is called.

But the input to enter your message text, is in the component `ChatForm`:

```
class ChatForm extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    return (<div className="chat-form">

      // THIS IS THE INPUT I NEED TO FOCUS ON
      <input className="input-form"
        placeholder="Your message..."
        ref="SHOULDFOCUS-HERE"
        autofocus="true" />

    </div>);
  }
}
```

so, from the main component, what should I do in order to focus on that input since in another component ?

Comment: Is there something weird about the display of this form that you need to focus the input with JavaScript?

Comment: @Mathletics is a big form, all I need is to focus that input when you click in the `dealer-player-box` div, that is it. Is just a requirement.

Comment: Do you expect the user to click _outside_ the input?

Comment: @Mathletics yes, the user sometimes could click in any other part of the chat box, and anyways the input should be focused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a ref to your ChatForm:

```
<ChatForm ref="chatForm" onAddMessage={this.addMessage} />;
```

In your `ChatForm` change the input ref to something meaningful:

```
<input className="input-form"
        placeholder="Your message..."
        ref="chatInput"
        autofocus="true" />
```

In your `ChatForm` component add a method which focuses:

```
focusInput() {
  this.refs.chatInput.focus();
}
```

In your `ChatView` component modify the `_inputFocus` method:

```
_inputFocus() {
  this.refs.chatForm.focusInput();
}
```

Note that using refs might be a little different if you are using deprecated versions of react (<0.14).

Comment: I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: this.refs.changeInput.focus is not a function` but I am using `"react": "~0.13.3"`, so with my version which is the solution ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer looks like it's calling the method ok, but to get the DOMNode in react 0.13 you have to do `this.refs.changeInput.getDOMNode()` i.e. `this.refs.changeInput.getDOMNode().focus()`